# Crawl a range of pages

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I'm new to C# and wanted to know whats the best way to crawl a range of pages.

If I want to take the source of many pages like this:
http://website.com/list/1 - http://website.com/list/44

How can I make it crawl each page in the range of 1-44?

Thanks :)

Comment: You are new to C#. It's ok I'm a junior too... But, did you ever use google for it( crawling webpages in C# ) before to come here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a nice and easy way not the most generic webcrawler but will help you with your current specifications

```
for(int i = 1; i < 45;i++){
string url = "http://website.com/list/"+i;
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
myRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
//do something with the result
}
```

you will have to add this to your using statements

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
for(int i = 1; i < 45 ; i++)
{
    var pageContent = wc.DownloadString("http://website.com/list/" + i);
    // do your page content processing here
}
```

although obviously you'll want to add error handling to this.

---

Depending on what the target of your app is, you may need to call Dispose() on the WebClient after using it.  In some environments, WebClient implements IDisposable, and in others it doesn't.  Thanks to @Paulo Moretti in the comments for mentioning it.

Comment: s/website.com/stackoverflow.com/ - s/list/questions/ - or you could just go download the open data :-D

Comment: @Paulo Moretti - Depends on the application type.  In the Windows Phone space, for example, it does implement IDisposable so it's easier to not mention it in the answer.

Comment: @ZombieSheep Your objection is valid. I just pointed out, because usually when people tag questions with C# is talking about .NET, rather than Silverlight.

Comment: @Paulo Moretti - I'll update the answer to mention it.  Thanks.